# OpenACC - Private 2D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, openacc

I'm dealing with block diagonal matrices (each blocks has the same size) and I have an `illegal address error` when I use `private` dynamically allocated 2D array...

```
// NB is the number of block
// N is the block size
// A is the main matrix (block diagonal)

double** B; // a block
B = new double*[N];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    B[i] = new double[N];

#pragma acc parallel loop private(B[:N][:N]) copyin(A[:NB*N][:NB*N])
for (unsigned int b = 0; b < NB; b++) {
    #pragma acc loop
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        #pragma acc loop
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            B[i][j] = A[b*N+i][b*N+j];
        }
    }
    // process B
}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    delete[] B[i];
delete[] B;
```

The error I get is:

```
call to cuStreamSynchronize returned error 700: Illegal address during kernel execution
```

It works fine if I flatten the array into a 1D array and use lexicographic index or static 2D array but I'm using function requiring a `double**` as parameter so I would prefer to stick with dynamic 2D array...

I've read up on the `private` clause in the spec but it doesn't say that dynamic 2D array are not supported so I suppose I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: what are the dimensions of `A` ?

Comment: @tobi303 `A` is an `N*NBxN*NB` matrix. Sorry `A` is **block diagonal**, I just edited that. Each block is an `NxN` matrix and `A` is composed of `NB` blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but using a array of pointers in a private clause isn't supported.  The problem being that the compiler runtime would have to dynamically create a private for each gang, worker, or vector (depending upon the loop with the private clause) and fill in all the device pointers.  This would come with an extremely high overhead cost.

If "B" is a fixed size static array, "double B[N][N]", then you could use it in the private clause.

Otherwise, I would suggest manually privatizing the array by adding a third dimension.

```
 // NB is the number of block
// N is the block size
// A is the main matrix (block diagonal)

double*** B; // a block
B = new double**[NB];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NB; i++) {
  B[i] = new double*[N];
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    B[i][j] = new double[N];
}}


#pragma acc parallel loop create(B[:NB][:N][:N]) copyin(A[:NB*N][:NB*N])
for (unsigned int b = 0; b < NB; b++) {
    #pragma acc loop
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        #pragma acc loop
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            B[b][i][j] = A[b*N+i][b*N+j];
        }
    }
    // process B
}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NB; i++) {
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
     delete[] B[i][j];
  }
  delete[] B[i];
}
delete[] B;
```